# display:column header shows wrong href url

Tags: sorting, struts2, displaytag

I have made a display tag column sortable using the below code:

```
<display:column style="text-align:center;" title="Column Title" sortable="true" sortProperty="lookUpCode" property="columnProperty"/>
```

After the table is rendered on the UI, on mouse over the anchor link of header is pointing to JSP rather than the controller. I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Okay @RomanC. Thank you for the comment. After the page is rendered, when I mouse over on the column header this the href shows that it is pointing to JSP rather than the controller with which the table is loaded. Is there any configuration to do to point to right url?

Answer (score 1):

basically display:column works in relation to display:table. So if we don't specify **requestURI** attribute to display:table tag, display:column will pick the loaded JSP as the **requestURI** for sorting. So after specifying the requestURI to display:table tag. My sorting is working as expected.

Here is the code snippet which worked for me. We don't have to give actual URI here. Even the empty URI works.

`<display:table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;" class="TAB dataTable" id="tableId" name="tableName" requestURI="">
    <display:column style="text-align:center;" title="Column Title" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>`